# What's the term for saying "go to a show as a guest"?

Tags: word-request

Go to a show as a guest is a bit wordy, but I can't find a single word that means exactly that, or even a short phrasal verb that means that. Is there anything I can use?

For example:

> Tom Cruise ____ the Maury Show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the phrase: "makes an appearance on." Tom Cruise makes an appearance on the Maury Show. Or a shorter version: Tom Cruise **appears** on the Maury Show.  If Tom Cruise is not a regular member of the cast, then it should be clear that he is on the show as a guest.